# Gradle doesn't compile .java to .class in jar file

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to compile a jar file in Android Studio, so far this works, the problem is that when I want to read from it in Unity3D, i can't. I found out that this is because the jar contains .java source inside of instead of .class files.

I work with the gradle file below:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
}

task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/libs/mysdk.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'mysdk.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)



task jarTask(type: Jar) {
    baseName="my-sdk-android"
    from 'src/main/java'
}

task createJarWithDependencies(type: Jar) {
    baseName = "my-sdk-android-jar-with-dependencies"
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    with jarTask
}

configurations {
    jarConfiguration
}

artifacts {
    jarConfiguration jarTask
}
```

I'm new to gradle, so if I have to make chances to my file please let me know what code to replace with what.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably putting the wrong folder into the jar file. Android Studio and Cradle **do** compile Java files into class files. You just need to find the correct folder where these class files are located.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have my .java files in android studio located in the app/java/packagename folder (these are 6 .java files). I'm a 100% sure they aren't in the .jar file as .class files, they are only in there in as .java files (packagename/<and then the files>). I have build a simple .jar file with Ant, this compiles it and makes classes out of it.
I tried to use the command gradlew compileJava in Android Studio, this gives some weird errors that I don't get when building the .jar file, might this be the problem?

Comment: @davidschep Does your library include any Android-specific code or resources? (As opposed to just generic Java). If so, you should build an AAR file instead of a JAR.

Comment: @davidschep As for the errors, you need to post a new question and include the error messages in order to get help.

Comment: It does contain some imported Android and Google libraries yes, I've gotten so far that my scripts exports these dependencies with the jar, the thing that I'm trying to achieve is a jar file (that I use in Unity3D with C#) from which I can access methods that are Android and Google Fit API specific. I don't think a AAR would work for that since Unity doesn't support reading methods from an AAR?

Comment: @davidschep An AAR is esentially a JAR which also includes XML and other resources. Doesn't Unity3D already have built-in support for the Android APIs?

Comment: @davidschep When I create a new project the .class files are compiled to `<project>/<module>/build/intermediates/classes/debug`. For the release build config replace the final folder with `release`.

Comment: Thanks! Having the location of the build classes is really nice, Unity3D has some android support, not for Google Fit though. I tried manually dragging the classes in the jar file, this worked for 4 out of 6 classes, the other two contained // INTERNAL ERROR // when decompiling them, while before dragging them into the jar they both were good code when decompiling. I'll look in to this more on Monday, since it's way too late right now and I work on Mondays till Fridays :) I'll keep you and others reading this thread posted, thanks for the great help already and have a great weekend!

Comment: @davidschep why are you decompiling?

Comment: @davidschep also note that the directory I gave earlier is the location of compiled class files for coffee that you write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by manually dragging the class files into the jar file. This works now.